# Чем на самом деле является переменная массива?

Tags: c++

Что такое переменная на массив?

```
int arr[10]{};
std::cout << arr;
```

Почему если это не указатель, то в переменной arr хранится адрес первого элемента

Comment: В переменной `arr` не хранится адрес первого элемента массива... Однако она может неявно приводится к указателю на первый элемент массива в подходящем контексте.

Comment: При выводе переменной типа int мы получаем её значение, при обращении к массиву типа int мы получаем адрес массива типа int, а при оператор [] используется для получения значения  с указанным индексом ( int ) из массива. Например int second = arr[1];